# How can tell if there is a prime number between any two numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers

Is there a conjecture, statement, formula or anything that determines whether or not there is a prime between two numbers? I'm not looking for a computer algorithm. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)?

Comment: Whether there exists a prime between any two positive integers depends on the size of the interval between them.  See [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) and refinements thereto.

Comment: Thank you that is what I need.

Comment: we can actually iterate bertrand to show either there's a prime between $n$ and $\lceil{4n\over 3}\rceil$ or two between $\lfloor{2n\over 3}\rfloor$ and $2n$

Comment: How can I do that? @Roddy MacPhee

Comment: it's literally use overlapping bounds ...

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt this is possible. Otherwise you could simply check any number of being prime, just by considering the number itself and the number +1 or something along these lines. But checking numbers being prime is hard...

Answer (score 0):

Bertrand's postulate in loose terms says:

There is alway a prime between $n$ and $2n$

Once we know this we can iterate it by shrinking or enlarging $n$ we get statements like:

- There is always a prime between $\lfloor {2n\over 3}\rfloor$ and $\lceil{4n\over 3}\rceil$
- There is always a prime between $\lfloor {3n\over 4}\rfloor$ and $\lceil{3n\over 2}\rceil$
- $\ldots$

rounding is simply to make sure we land on integers. However there's overlap between our intervals, therefore we get :

- Either there's a prime in the insection of these intervals, with the original, or there are two primes in the complement to their intersection.

We can break this down to 5 intervals that don't intersect( or minimally) with implications on each other:

- There is always either a prime between $n$ and $\lceil{4n\over 3}\rceil$  or one between $\lfloor {2n\over 3}\rfloor$ and $\lceil{3n\over 4}\rceil$  or $\lfloor {4n\over 3}\rfloor$ and $\lceil{3n\over 2}\rceil$  otherwise there's an interval where you can double a number without a prime.
- There is always either a prime between $n$ and $\lceil{3n\over 2}\rceil$  or one between $\lceil{3n\over 2}\rceil$ and $2n$.  otherwise there's an interval where you can double a number without a prime.
- There is always either a prime between $\lfloor {3n\over 4}\rfloor$ and $\lceil{4n\over 3}\rceil$  or one between $\lfloor{2n\over 3}\rfloor$ and $\lceil {3n\over 4}\rceil$ .  Otherwise there's an interval where you can double a number without a prime.

etc.

**numeric example**

if n=8

then

6 to 12 and 8 to 16 each have a prime, but it could be the same prime in each range because they overlap in between 8 and 12. If this weren't true  ( 11 is prime, but lets say it isn't for a moment), we'd get that both of the ranges 6 to 8 and 12 to 16 would require primes for Bertrands postulate to hold. I used a pseudoexample here, because
up to n=100 000 it's never true that center range doesn't have a prime.

Answer (score -1):

The best we can do is that for any $x \ge 89693$ there is always at least one prime between $x$ and $x + \dfrac{1}{\log^3 x}$. This is much stronger than Bertrand's postulate and was proved by Pierre Dusart.

Comment: try iterating it ?